# Iterate between incremental ID inputs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, jquery-selectors

I have some inputs in my HTML that have ID's such as `element1`, `element2`, `element3`, ...`elementN`

If I want to use the selector on every element, I don't want to make one for each element like this: `$("#element1")` is there a way to use a `for` loop to iterate between `element1` and `elementN` using jQuery?

EDIT: I need to perform verifications with another incremental ID's like this

```
var X1 = $("#element1").val();
var X2 = $("#anotherElement1").val();
if (X1 == X2)
{ 
//do something
}
```

Edit2 (Added context)

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Element1 must be a 
number." id="Element1 " max="1000" min="0" name="EnergyAt1" step="0,1" type="text" value="18,3" 
data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria-valuemin="0" 
aria-valuemax="1000" 
class="k-input" aria-valuenow="18,3" aria-disabled="false" style="display: none;">

<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AnotherElement1 must be a 
number." id="AnotherElement1 " max="1000" min="0" name="EnergyAt1" step="0,1" 
type="text" value="18,3" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" aria- 
valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="1000" class="k-input" aria-valuenow="18,3" aria- 
disabled="false" style="display: none;">
```

What i need to do is a function bound to my submit button that checks, for every element between 1 and N that if ( ElementX.val() != 0 && AnotherElementX == 0) prevents the submit of the form.

Comment: Use a single common `class`. This is one of the reasons incremental `id` attributes are an anti-pattern

Comment: Not really gonna cut it, because i have other inputs named differently with incremental ID's that i need to perform verifications on.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a reason not to use classes. If anything, it sounds like *more* of a reason to use classes properly.

Comment: It would be nice if you could expand this example with a little bit of an example of what the html elements look like, and also expand on what X3 for example would be compared with in your demo. Are they all supposed to be compared to each other? In sets? Unicorn?

Comment: Did that in Edit2.

Comment: @Ribeiro The `id` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to several reasons, I couldn't use classes as recommended, I ended up building a for loop around my use case with a colleague's help, here's the code:

```
function checkIfAnotherElementIsZero(e) {
        var canSubmit = true;
        for (let i = 1; i <= 24; i++)
        {
            if ($("#Element" + i).val() != 0 && $("#AnotherElement" + i).val() == 0) 
            {
                alert('Error');
                canSubmit = false;
                break;
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        if (canSubmit == true)
        {
             $( "input[name=Date]" ).addClass( "data-val-ignore" );
             $( "#@ContextControllerName" ).submit();
        }
        else
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that every ID which starts with `element` is what you want to select, you can use the selector string `[id^="element"]`, which will select everything whose `id` starts with `element`:

```js
$('[id^="element"]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1">e1</div>
<div id="element2">e2</div>
<div id="element3">e3</div>
<div id="element4">e4</div>
```

But if at all possible, use classes instead - `id`s are not very appropriate in this sort of situation:

```js
$('.element').each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="element">e1</div>
<div class="element">e2</div>
<div class="element">e3</div>
<div class="element">e4</div>
```

Comment: That's a great answer but I couldn't replicate it within my code with success, I've posted what worked for me in a post bellow.